# Can I declare local/temp variables within a jQuery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Is it possible to declare new variables within the jQuery template syntax? I'm hoping to achieve the equivalent of this (which does not work):

```
{{var test = "test"}}

<div>
    ${test}
</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you declare the variable where you use the template? or make your own custom "template extension" that takes common practices and separates them from typical template usage.

Comment: Because the context of the variable is related to the template logic and should remain encapsulated within the template. For example, what if I want to set a boolean flag if something is encountered in an {{each}} loop, and then have the template display something different in a few places later on, depending on that boolean value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty lame, but one trick that might work is:

```
  {{each(i, test) ["test"]}}
    blah blah ${test} blah
  {{/each}}
```

I'm not 100% sure however about using an array constant expression like that; I'll set up a fiddle. (*edit* yes it works :-)

Comment: Woa, cool. What exactly is `["test"]`? A quick search for array constant expression didn't appear to be helpful.

Comment: It's just an array with a single string in it ("test").  The idea of "{{each}}" is to iterate, but a side-effect is that you get to set a variable to the value of an expression. With that hack, you could put any expression you wanted in place of `["test"]` for the value of the loop variable - it just has to be an array, with one value in it :-)

Comment: Haha, definitely one heck of a hack! Accepting answer because it works, upvoting for the creativity. :-D

Comment: Yup, I think this is a crafty solution, sir.

Answer (score 23):

I know this has already been answered and accepted, but here is another solution:

```
${( $data.localVariable = 'SOMETHING' ),''}
```

A jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/PrfZ5/

Comment: This is a really clean implementation that I've started using. With this syntax, it's very easy to define local variables in my templates that would otherwise require expensive calls into my model. (I'm currently using this with KnockoutJS.) Thanks for a straightforward solution that doesn't rely on tricks or hacks.

Comment: simple and elegant. definitely the way I'll do it from now

Comment: Thanks. It really works. I use it when I have a lot of if, else, if, else, etc.

Comment: I'm into a similar situation, and I need to assign the value to the `localVariable` at runtime. I tried using the object notations, but didn't work. Is it possible? I want to do something like this:

`${( $data.localVariable = testObject.name ),''}`

`testObject` is the response from the server which I'm operating on in my template. 

TIA.

Comment: If you pass ${localVariable } to another template, how do you then access that data in the next template?