# Can a jquery template have a for loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I need to build a jQuery template that has a month dropdown and a day of the month dropdown in it.  It seems like overkill for me to have to include a month list and a day list in each of my JSON model items that has values 1 to 31 just so that I can build options with the {{each}} syntax.

I've seen how you can add a dynamic array inside of {{each}} in another answer:
[Can I declare local/temp variables within a jQuery template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147766/can-i-declare-local-temp-variables-within-a-jquery-template)

I can probably just define an array inside that with values 1 to 31.  But even that is a little verbose.  Is there a better way to do a for loop in jquery templates?

I can probably find some date object to iterate for the date specific case, but what about a non date related for loop use case?

I want the loop fully defined in the template body without using an external global variable.  With a global variable, I could easily use {{each}}.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found how to add another tag to jquery templates.  Here is the for tag definition.  Add this after your script references to jquery and jquery.tmpl.js:

```
(function ($) {
$.extend(jQuery.tmpl.tag, {
    "for": {
        _default: {$2: "var i=1;i<=1;i++"},
        open: 'for ($2){',
        close: '};'
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for a sample for a textarea tag by Roel Kramers:
http://blog.sterkwebwerk.nl/2010/12/15/custom-jquery-template-tags-1/

Also viewing the jquery.tmpl source for the definition of the each tag helped a lot.

The default is a for loop with 1 iteration.  Here is how you define a template body to use it:

```
<script id="TestTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    Day:<br/>
    <select name="DayOfMonth">
        {{for(i=1;i<=31;i++)}}
        <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
        {{/for }}
    </select>
</script>​
```

Here is a jsFiddle page to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/mjlang/qvzdV/

Comment: A heads up, that fiddle does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: The fiddle may not work because jQuery templates are obsolete.  This answer is here for historical purposes at this point.  Use another template engine like jsRender.