# Using a variable in jQuery template with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery template plugin (jquery.tmpl.min.js - v 1.0.0pre). My sample response object looks like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
    "responseMessage": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 92,
            "messageRead": false,
            "importance": null,
            "message": {
                "id": 86,
                "createdDate": 1414393557000,
                "messageType": "TESTTYPE",
                "subject": "test sub",
                "message": "test item",
                "fromOrg": 3,
                "accessCode": 2,
                "fromUserId": 1,
                "users": null,
                "read": false,
                "fromOrganizationName": null,
                "messageAttachment": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "createdDate": 1414393816000,
                        "name": "README"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In my template, while iterating over `messageAttachment` array, I need to access `fromOrg` inside the `{{each messageAttachment}}` loop.

```
{{if message.messageAttachment.length > 0 }}
    {{each message.messageAttachment}}
        \${name} <br/>
        ---- I need value of fromOrg here---
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

How can I achieve this? My take on this is to declare a variable before looping `messageAttachment` array and use that variable inside the loop. I referred to this SO:

[Can I declare local/temp variables within a jQuery template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147766/can-i-declare-local-temp-variables-within-a-jquery-template)

I tried to use this `${( $data.localVariable = 'SOMETHING' ),''}` but unable to assign a runtime value instead of `SOMETTHING`.

Also, of there is any other way, please share. Any pointers appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Uh, that would be just `message.fromOrg`, note that it doesn't change in your loop, as there's no `fromOrg` inside the `messageAttachment` array ?

Comment: Oh, never thought of trying it out. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @adeneo - However, is there any way to assign runtime value to `localVariable`? Instead of `SOMETHING` as being done here - `${( $data.localVariable = 'SOMETHING' ),''}` - Like `${( $data.localVariable = message.fromOrg ),''}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @adeneo, it can be directly accessed as `message.fromOrg` since there is no `fromOrg` inside `messageAttachment` array.